# Unable to sync outlook attendees to sharepoint 2010 calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

My scenario is I have a SharePoint 2010 calendar which has been sync to outlook 2010 calendar and when I create a new event from outlook it is not showing attendees in my SharePoint calendar list. IS there any settings or workaround for this.